# mysql consult in same table

Tags: mysql

i have this table

```
INSERT INTO `relationships` (`id`, `term_id`, `order`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(4, 2, 0),
(4, 3, 0),
(4, 4, 0),
(4, 5, 0),
(4, 7, 0),
(4, 8, 0),
(6, 3, 0),
(6, 8, 0),
(6, 9, 0),
(8, 6, 0),
(8, 7, 0),
(8, 8, 0),
(8, 10, 0),
(15, 3, 0),
(15, 4, 0),
(15, 10, 0);
```

I need to select all term_id containing the number 8 and 5 (relationship between this numbers)

expected result = id 4 and id 8

I try this

```
SELECT `id` FROM `relationships` WHERE `term_id`=8 or `term_id`=5
```

but selects all term_id belong to 8 and 5

result = id 4 id 8 AND id --> 6 <-- This is not the result I want.

Comment: Something here unclear. You want to select all id's where term_id in 8 and 5? So whats wrong with your results? Why you don't want to have 6 in your result?

Comment: If you want the id's where term_id of 8 and 5 are both listed, then 4 would appear but not 8.

Comment: @Alex that because It should be. If you use `AND` operator you will get empty result set.

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas Yeah, sorry my bad :)

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word - a poor choice for a table/column identifier, with or without backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM relationships a
WHERE 
  a.term_id = 5 AND 
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM relationships b WHERE b.term_id = 8 AND b.id = a.id) > 0
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e78cc/4/0

Comment: This only returns `4` contrary to the expected result.

Comment: @paco-abato look at the data provided, and back at the results.. Hint try to add "(8, **5**, 0)" to the data (and Paul comment above)